# Can read CANBUS socket, but not write to it

Tags: c, linux, sockets, can-bus

I'm converting a Windows program to Linux and I have some problem writing to the CAN bus. Trying `write` or `send` returns -1 with `errno` as "No such device or address"

Some simplified C code:

```
int s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);
if (s < 0) { perror("socket"); return errno; }

struct sockaddr_can addr;
addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
struct ifreq ifr;
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "any");
addr.can_ifindex = 0; // any can interface

if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind"); return errno; 
}

struct can_frame frame={0};
int nbytes = recv(s, &frame, sizeof(frame), MSG_DONTWAIT);
// The above works. Not the following:
struct can_frame frame={0x123, 2, .data={1, 2}};
int nbytes = send(s, &frame, sizeof(frame), 0);
// nbytes=-1, errno=6 "No such device or address"
```

Comment: Is the name of your can interface really `any` and not `can0`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, it fails with `any` but it works with `vcan0`. Thank! I'll see what the difference is in more details.

Comment: I guess that socketcan is intelligent that if you read from `any`, then it will poll from all active can interfaces. However, if you try to write, then which one should it use? And that's why it fails. I don't know, I never use `any` as the interface name.